# How do I send a date stored in a field of a table in a Mysql database to a javascript variable to calculate the time between two date?

Tags: javascript

I found the following:

```
// Set the date we're counting down to

    var countDownDate = new Date ("Jun 23, 2017 19:00:00"). getTime ();

// Update the count down every 1 second

    var x = setInterval (function () {})

// Get todays date and time       

    var now = new Date (). getTime ();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date       

    var distance = countDownDate - now;
```

What I cannot do is replace **"Jun 23, 2017 19:00:00"** with the variable where I store the value of the date in the database

I get the variable with PHP and save it **@ date1**

Something like this: `var countDownDate = new Date ("@ date1"). GetTime ();`

Comment: Your `setInterval` is incomplete and you haven't mentioned what type of data is returned from your PHP Script, is it  a String date of the format `Mon DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS`? Do you assign it to a local variable in javascript?

Comment: You can also use cookie, using setcookie method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it either on page load or via javascript.

On page load you can assign javascript variable like below and can consume as it is.

```
var date1 = <?php echo $data1?>;
```

On ajax, you can get the output from the server and then use it accordingly.